# K8s : Read value from container files (mounted under specific path) in env variable

Tags: kubernetes

I want to read a values from container file(mounted under specific path) in an environment variable in Kubernetes.

```
Ex:
/etc/mysql/default/uri -> file contains the uri
/etc/mysql/default/username -> file contains the username
/etc/mysql/default/password -> file contains the password
```

I want to read these values in evn variable in K8s.

Something like below:

```
env:
 - name: MYSQL_URI
   value: "/etc/mysql/default/uri"
 - name: MYSQL_USERNAME
   value: "/etc/mysql/default/username"
```

Is this a correct way to do it? If not, what should be the right approach?

Comment: Note that such questions have more chances to be answered on ServerFault for instance as they do not directly relate to development.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you to do exactly with your process but you can achieve this by passing some command in your kubernetes container like with export command in bash =>

```html
export MYSQL_URI=$(cat /etc/mysql/default/uri);
```

i didnt tried at all but it might work directly like this =>

```html
env:
  - name: MYSQL_URI
    value: "$(cat /etc/mysql/default/uri)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that this way.

If the files are hard coded in the container image (which is not a best practice, as you'd need to rebuild the image to change credentials + they would be in clear for anyone that can download the image), then make your container process read values from these files directly. Kubernetes is not involved at all in this process.

Otherwise, use a Kubernetes `ConfigMap` and load it as env variables in the container.

Comment: the files are supposed to be mounted volume as long as he doesn't push the image to a public repository there's no problem right?

Comment: If the files are mounted as volume it's okay but then why not directly use proper ConfigMap.

Comment: yes configmap better can't deny :)